# Force group by to keep the original order of the rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a result of a query like this:

```
24
1
24
11
11
11
13
24
24
11
24
11
24
11
11
13
24
24
11
11
13
21
21
11
11
11
11
11
7
11
11
```

I need to group this result, but if I simply group by this id mysql also orders it like:

```
1
2
3
4
```

What I want is:

```
24
1
11
13
21
```

.
.
.

Would it be possible?

The complete query is this one, basically it calculates the closest routes that have a business inside based on given coordinates:

```
select * from (select dr.*  from drivers_route dr inner join businesses_drivers_route bdr on dr.id_drivers_route = bdr.fk_id_drivers_route inner join  (select * from (select b.idbusiness, 
       b.trading_as,  
       111.1111 *
       DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(53.33841959999999))          * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(-6.2876401 - b.longitude))
         + SIN(RADIANS(53.33841959999999))
         * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude)))) AS distance_in_km from business b inner join business_category bc on bc.fk_idbusiness = b.idbusiness where b.status_reg = 'A'   and bc.status_reg = 'A'   and bc.fk_idcategory=44) as b_dist order by b_dist.distance_in_km) as b_ord on b_ord.idbusiness = bdr.fk_id_bus_destination) as r_ord;
```

Comment: show your query and your table structure

Comment: No. You need some kind of index, e.g. a PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding counter in the query like this:

**SET @c=0;**
SELECT my_field,**(@c := @c +1) as c** FROM `my_table` group by my_field **order by c**;

But as Strawberry said, it is good to have a unique primary key so you can use it instead.

Comment: I'm in a single query here, not in a stored procedure, don't thing I can use this in a single query execution, can I?

Comment: You can, but you need to do this in seperate querys, like:
1. mysql_query("SET @c=0;")
2. mysql_query(...full query...)

Comment: Just tested in workbench and it works perfect, now will test under hibernate queries.

Comment: I would appreciate if you marked this answer as good, if you think so.

Comment: The answer is good, just struggling to escape the : (colon) in hibernate now, before setting it as answered =)

Comment: Perfect, just had to use an interceptor EmptyInterceptor for Hibernate to workaround the fact that hibernate consider colon as a parameter and the version of Hibernate we are using here does not escape it properly just by using \\.